# Error in email sending during testcase in django?

Tags: python, django, testcase

I have a simple django application which allows users to add a new user.Whenever we created a new user,a mail will send to that respective email-id (what we gave while creating a new user).If i have added any new user with email say xxxx@xxxx.com,a mail will send succesfully to xxxx@xxxx.com.I have no problem here.

But when I try to write a testcase for adding a new user, I got error in email sending line in my code...ie `TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 non-keyword arguments (6 given)`.
The code is given below,

```
#from my views.py,

Email().send_email(settings.FORGOT_SUBJECT, emailmessage, [username], 
   settings.CONTENT_TYPE)`
```

pls remember i have no problem in this line while created a user from webpage & the mail send sucesfully.only getting error in this line during testcase.

```
# code for SMTP connection
class Email:

    def __init__(self):
        return;

    def send_email(self, subject, message, recipients, contenttype):
        """
        Send email using smtp connection.
        """
        try:
            from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, SMTPConnection, send_mail
            from settings import EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, EMAIL_PORT, EMAIL_USE_TLS
        finally:
            connection = SMTPConnection(EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT, EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, EMAIL_USE_TLS)
            emailMessage = EmailMessage(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, recipients)
            emailMessage.content_subtype = contenttype
            connection.send_messages([emailMessage])
```

Pls give any solution to avoid this error.

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 non-keyword arguments (6 given)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the backtrace, and the testcode you're seeing the problem with

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be writing something that isn't Python.

That `__init__` method does nothing. Remove it.

In fact, remove the class altogether. This isn't Java: if you're not storing state or encapsulating functionality, there's no reason to have a class. Just use the `send_email` function on its own.